# <base href="/app/"> is not working in my angular application

Tags: angularjs

FOr my angular application , I  want to use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to remove '#' sign from URL.
I also used   but it is not working.

My index.html include   "" in header section.

My app.js is as follows.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/signIn', {
        controller: 'signInController',
        templateUrl: 'html/views/sign-in.html'

    })
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'html/views/log-in.html'
    })


    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

All my code (html and scripts) is under App directory. But when I am trying to run my login page is not getting loaded.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, is that the only code in your app.js file? Your $routeProvider... needs to go inside the config function (you will need to inject $routeProvider & $locationProvider into this function) which is available off a module declaration. Also, you'll have to include the angular-route.js since routing functionality was separated a few releases ago.

Comment: My $routeProvider is in config only. I added only $routeProvider code here.There is no error in console.

Comment: Are you running this on a web server? If not, give that a try.

Comment: yes I did ..but same response.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant code for app.js and index.html so I can try it at my end here?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?  You may find this useful for ng2 rc.1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set