# Angular 2 router no base href set

Tags: angular, routes, href

I am getting an error and can't find why. Here is the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of LocationStrategy! (RouterOutlet -> Router -> Location -> LocationStrategy).
    angular2.dev.js:23514 EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of LocationStrategy! (RouterOutlet -> Router -> Location -> LocationStrategy).BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23525ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1145(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:5751run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
    angular2.dev.js:23514 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1154(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:5751run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
    angular2.dev.js:23514 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1157(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:5751run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
    angular2.dev.js:23514 Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.
        at new BaseException (angular2.dev.js:8080)
        at new PathLocationStrategy (router.dev.js:1203)
        at angular2.dev.js:1380
        at Injector._instantiate (angular2.dev.js:11923)
        at Injector._instantiateProvider (angular2.dev.js:11859)
        at Injector._new (angular2.dev.js:11849)
        at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (angular2.dev.js:11733)
        at Injector._getByKeyDefault (angular2.dev.js:12048)
        at Injector._getByKey (angular2.dev.js:12002)
        at Injector._getByDependency (angular2.dev.js:11990)
```

Does anyone know why the router is throwing this? I am using angular2 beta

here is my code:

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './pages/login/login.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template:`
        <div class="wrapper">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/',redirectTo: '/dashboard' },
    { path: '/login',name:'login',component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/dashboard',name:'dashboard',component: DashboardComponent,}
])
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 413, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the `<head>` tag. If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the `href` value *exactly* as shown here.

The `<base href="/">` tells the Angular router what is the static part of the URL. The router then only modifies the remaining part of the URL.

```ts
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Alternatively add

**>= Angular2 RC.6**

```ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [routing /* or RouterModule */], 
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
]);
```

in your bootstrap.

In older versions the imports had to be like

**< Angular2 RC.6**

```ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' });
]);
```

**< RC.0**

```ts
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' });
]);
```

**< beta.17**

```ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
```

**>= beta.17**

```ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/platform/common';
```

See also [Location and HashLocationStrategy stopped working in beta.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16/36861629#36861629)

Comment: Little example of second way: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/'})]);`

Comment: I had to add the import line `import {provide} from 'angular2/core';` to be able to use provide.

Comment: I had to import line `import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';`

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I don't use TS myself (only Dart) and my TS knowledge is still limited.

Comment: I strongly recommend to include project directory structure here to make it more clear. I made an error by just include <base href="/"> in my project, because of the different project directory structure. It took me some time to figure out the reason.

Comment: What's you Project structure. `/` is common, for specific cases this might need a different path.

Comment: as of this day, (january 14th 2017), <base href="/"> works fine for me, except when trying to test my app using TestBed. In this case, I have to provide a APP_BASE_HREF

Comment: @JCorriveau yes, it's supposed to work. Only when you serve the application on a subdirectory like `http://example.org/somesub/index.html` or similar, then you need a different path like `base="/somesub"`

Comment: My project has SVG elements filled with image patterns. The images were never displayed in Firefox when `<base href="/" />` was set in the file (for `"/"`, `"./"`, `"#"` or any other base path, no matter how the image paths themselves were specified in the pattern). The only solution that finally worked was to use `APP_BASE_HREF` instead. A real life saver!

Comment: hold on, but <base href="/"> is exactly the reason why angular builds are unable to be opened just by opening index.html from local folder (without web server)... I don't understand why angular need this base href

Comment: I doubt this is related. Angular needs a server because of security constraints in the browser (can be disabled by command line arguments). Angular can instead of `<base>` also be configured with `APP_BASE_HREF`

Comment: I want to add to your answer, if you have in your source index.html a <base> tag, it will override any APP_BASE_HREF or ng build --base-href; values. After removng it, I can modify the base href from any means.

Comment: @DamjanDimitrioski I had expected the opposite. **Inside Angular code** `APP_BASE_HREF` should override `<base href="...">`. `APP_BASE_HREF` doesn't affect other areas where `<base href="...">` has an effect, like SVG refs or similar.

Comment: So, what's causing ng build to ignore the APP_BASE_HREF if base href is set in src index.html, in Angular 5.x ?

Comment: @DamjanDimitrioski not sure what you mean with "ignore the APP_BASE_HREF". `APP_BASE_HREF` is only used by Angular code like the router or some custom code that might inject `APP_BASE_HREF`. Perhaps you expect it to have some effect it is not supposed to have?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I expected setting --base-href /mypath to update the <base href="/mypath", but it didn't, removing the <base> from index.html(source) created the tag in the dist directory. This behaviour was not explained in any docs I read.

Comment: I don't know about `--base-href ...`, but that doesn't seem to be related to `APP_BASE_HREF`, only to `<base href="...">`

Comment: This is the right answer.
I get this every time I create a new `*.spec.ts` test file.
It is always required to build up a complete running environment.

Comment: I had this error on a test `.spec.ts` while using `Location`. I add the `RouterTestingModule` and the error goes away

Comment: Using {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' } worked for me

Comment: Not working. Angular modules start throwing NullInjector errors

Comment: does this mean you have to hardcode the base in the index file if you're not using the HashLocationStrategy? this would be a problem when deploying in a context which is not root, isn't there a better solution without having to change the index file?

Comment: @magomarcelo You can use string replacement in a build step, or use some JavaScript to change the value before Angular is started for example deriving it from the current location. There are probably other ways I'm not thinking of currently.

Answer (score 38):

I had faced similar issue with Angular4 and Jasmine unit tests; below given solution worked for me

Add below import statement

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

Add below statement for TestBed configuration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 16):

Angular 7,8 fix is in app.module.ts

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
```

inside @NgModule add

`providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]`

Comment: I faced this error while trying to load a component for angular story book. This component had router dependency. It solved the error!!

Answer (score 12):

You can also use hash-based navigation by including the following in app.module.ts

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

and by adding the following to the @NgModule({ ... })

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers:    [
      ProductService, {
          provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy
      }
  ],
  ...
})
```

[image: Angular 2 Development with TypeScript]

“HashLocationStrategy—A hash sign (#) is added to the URL, and the URL segment after the hash uniquely identifies the route to be used as a web page fragment. This strategy works with all browsers, including the old ones.”

Excerpt From: Yakov Fain Anton Moiseev. “Angular 2 Development with TypeScript.”

Comment: Thanks Lionel! This is excellent and solved a problem I had using the APP_BASE_HREF solution above which fails when using url parameters like "product/:id". Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Since 2.0 beta :)

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from 'angular2/platform/common';
```

Comment: As of Rc6 this is all in the provider now: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html

Comment: This helped me when my spec in Karma was failing with  Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Answer (score 7):

it is just that add below code in the index.html head tag

```
   <html>
    <head>
     <base href="/">
      ...
```

that worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 6):

With angular 4 you can fix this issue by updating **app.module.ts** file as follows:

Add import statement at the top as below:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
```

And add below line inside `@NgModule`

```
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
```

Reff: https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Comment: Why does useValue need to be '/my/app'?

Answer (score 2):

Check your index.html.
If you have accidentally removed the following part, include it and it will be fine

```
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```