# Error during instantiation of LocationStrategy in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am developing an app in **angular-2** in which I have index page which will load my app component. app component content the routing to load home or login.

here is my index.html

```ts
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
    <style>
       *{
            border-radius: 0px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <app>Loading......</app>
    </div>
    <script>
       System.config({
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {        
          app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },
        paths: {
            'angular2/upgrade': '../node_modules/angular2/upgrade'
          }

      });
        System.import('scripts/src/bootstrap');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my **bootstrap.ts**

```ts
//import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';


import {App} from './components/app/app';
import {LoginService} from './services/loginService';
import {HttpService} from './services/httpServices';

bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LoginService, HttpService]);
```

here is my **app.ts**

```ts
import {Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet,  ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';


import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home';
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/app/app.html',
    directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet]
})
export class App {
    constructor( @Inject(Router) router: Router) {
        router.config([
            { path: '', as: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '/login', as: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]);
    }
}
```

which load my other component but when I run my app giving me  error.

[image]

please, correct me what I am missing here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update (2.0.0 final)**

```
@NgModule({
  providers [
    RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes), 
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : 'path'}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
]);
```

**original**

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the `<head>` tag. If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the `href` value *exactly* as shown here.

```
<base href="/">
```

Alternatively add

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : 'path'})
]);
```

in your bootstrap.

Comment: Why do you need this

Comment: This is used by the router and the Http module to calculate the full URL. It configures what the fix part of the URL is. I don't know full details myself.