# Redirect serving static files to root, html5 routing, angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, browser-sync, angular2-routing

I'm building an Angular 2 application and I'm using html5 routing.
I stumbled across a problem with nested routes. The problem is that when I have `/route1` defined, it works fine but in case of `/route1/child-route`, it is not working.

I use `browserSync` for serving the files and I use middleware to redirect to index.html. So far I have seen that the problem is with compiled TypeScript files and SystemJS that uses relative urls and for example when `app.js` is requested, the server is looking for the file in location `/route1/app.js`. Can anybody help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="/">` in the `<head>`? Does your server support HTML5 pushstate?

Comment: I forgot about this. Thanks, base url resolved it.

Comment: You didn't get this warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set ?

Comment: No i didn't it worked fine. Only problem was not serving the files right.

Comment: actually i already had set up `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})` in my boot.ts. I had not seen this problem before i used nested routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the `<head>` tag. If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the `href` value *exactly* as shown here.

```
<base href="/">
```

Alternatively add

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' });
]);
```

in your bootstrap.

Comment: is it necessary to provide `APP_BASE_HREF` in bootstrap ? only `base href` in the head tag is't enough ?

Comment: Yes in head is enough, `bootstrap()` is an alternative way of doing it. I allows to determine and set the path at runtime. This is for example used for plunkers where it's run in an iframe with an additional directory in the url.