# Angular2 import path wrong at runtime

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an angular2 app and at runtime it tries to load a resource from the wrong URL.

It should look for it at:
http://localhost:54675/app/services/angular2-jwt.js, but it looks for it at:
http://localhost:54675/app/**shared**/services/angular2-jwt.js.  The word shared should not be in the path.

I have this structure in angular2:

```
app
---services
------angular2-jwt.ts
---shared
------country
---------country.service.ts
```

In country.service.ts I reference angular2-jwt.ts like this:

```
import {AuthHttp} from '../../services/angular2-jwt';
```

As you can see, that's up two (into app) and down into services.  It should give this path:  app/services/angular2-jwt.
I look in the compiled js at looks correct:

```
System.register(['angular2/core', '../../services/angular2-jwt']
```

I am using Visual Studio and the intelliSense works.  I see AuthHttp in a popup as an option from that library.  I don't get an error when I save or build.  I think this is correct.

At runtime I get this error in the broswer console:

```
Error: Unable to load script: http://localhost:54675/app/shared/services/angular2-jwt.js
```

Notice the script URL path is wrong.  It has 'shared' as part of the path but should not.

I have caching disabled in my browser.  I look at the js source in the browser and I see that same source mentioned above.  It happens in chrome (my default) and Firefox (which I rarely use) so I don't think it's a caching issue.   How is it getting this path?

Here is my SystemJS configuraiton from index.html:

```
<script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I have now duplicated this on another machine.  However, I am importing this same module ('../../services/angular2-jwt') from a different file at a similar locaiton is the directory tree and it works.

Comment: I made a test with your folder structure and it works on my side. Could you give us your SystemJS configuration? Thanks!

Comment: Where do I find the SystemJS configuration?  I have the snippet in index.html.  I added that to the original post.

Comment: I have tried ../../../services/angular2-jwt.  It does not work.  Runtime error, and Intellisense will not wokr with that path.

Comment: Do you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256 set? Someone mentioned that the `bootstrap(... , [APP_BASE_HREF])` approach doesn't work when the `<head>` tag contains `<meta>` tags

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help.  I don't think this is related to the routing.  It happens on the initial page load.

Comment: Try adding `map: { app: "/" },` to the System.congif (as a sibling/at same level as `package`).

Comment: I tried that and now I get: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Comment: You are probably importing it wrong from another file. Are you sure this is the file that is causing the issue?

Comment: I'm sure.  If I take it out (and comment out what needs it) then I don't have a problem.  Plus, I search for that string with shared and services in the path and nothing is found.

Comment: Could you provide a small project that replicates this error?

Comment: @Don Chambers I tried it and it works fine, can you send a small project as "Daniel Rasmuson" sad, Or if you fix it already, tell as why it append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the import path to all components, not just this one.  I had bad syntax in a parent component and it caused this issue.

Comment: The file that uses country.service.ts is called country.picker.component. It was referenced from another component like this:
import {CountryPickerComponent} from '..//country/country.picker.component';  It had two slashes.  I changed this and it work.  It's weird that these components worked together but caused the problem in a import down the chain.

Notice the two double slashes. Once I changed this to on slash it worked.