# Template parse error: Unexpected closing tag

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm getting an error when reloading some of the routes in my app. First load works fine `http://localhost:8001`, and all other routes work from there. But if I reload page on some other route I get an exception below...

For example:

- `http://localhost:8001` works
- `http://localhost:8001/application` works
- `http://localhost:8001/application/` doesn't work
- `http://localhost:8001/application/add` doesn't work

**Anyone knows why is this happening?**

#### EXCEPTION:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "head" ("
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/default.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
[ERROR ->]</head>

<body>
"): RootRoute@12:0
Unexpected closing tag "html" ("
</body>

[ERROR ->]</html>"): RootRoute@38:0
```

#### root.route.ts:

```
@Component(...)
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', name: 'Root', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/application/...', name: 'Application', component: ApplicationRoute},
  { path: '/:unknown', redirectTo: ['/Root'] }
])
export class RootRoute {...}
```

#### application.route.ts:

```
@Component({ template: `<p>Dummy Template...</p>` })
export class Dummy {}

@Component(...)
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', name: 'Root', component: Dummy },
  { path: '/add', name: 'Add', component: Dummy }
])
export class ApplicationRoute extends RouteComponent {...}
```

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/default.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>

<body>
  <app class="theme-default">
    <div class="app-loader">
      loading
    </div>
  </app>
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="/static/scripts/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/http.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/router.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/scripts/system.conf.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->

  <!-- inject:brsync -->
  <script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:8888/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.11.1.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>

  <!-- endinject -->
</body>

</html>
```

## UPDATE:

I did some debugging and it turns out errors are generated by [`TemplateNormalizer`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/compiler/template_normalizer.ts), more specifically by [`HtmlParser.parse()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/compiler/html_parser.ts) method. When I removed `<meta>` tags from `<head>` errors were gone. But nothing else was happening - app didn't show - only `<div class="app-loader">` was rendered even though `SystemJS` loaded all the modules in the background...

I also noticed one of my services was returning weird results, turns out I used relative URL. This lead me to add `<base href="/">` to the header and that fixed all the issues... I'm not sure why, but it seams `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })` from `bootstrap.ts` is ignored in some places...

Comment: Did you add `<base>` or `APP_BASE_HREF` in `bootstrap`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yea, it's in bootstrap `provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })`...

Comment: ...everything works unless I reload browser on some of the routes.

Comment: set `useAsDefault: true` in the child routing of `application.route.ts` i.e we have to specify which route is to be open by default
`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Turns out you were right about `<base>` tag... Seams like `APP_BASE_HREF` from bootstrap was ignored for some reason. See my updated question... If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Try to add it last in the providers list in `bootstrap()` maybe there is another provider collection that contains it and overrides your custom one.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Didn't help.. still getting same error without `<base>` tag...

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work from `bootstrap()` when `<head>` contains a `<meta>` tag. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the `<head>` tag. If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the `href` value *exactly* as shown here.

```
<base href="/">
```

Alternatively add

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' });
]);
```

in your bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

change your application.route.ts with :

```
@Component({ template: `<p>Dummy Template...</p>` })
export class Dummy {}

@Component(...)
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', name: 'Root', component: Dummy, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/add', name: 'Add', component: Dummy }
])
export class ApplicationRoute extends RouteComponent {...}
```

Comment: That's not the issue, my app routes are terminal and specified. As docs state: `If useAsDefault is true, the child route will be navigated to if no child route is specified during the navigation.` If i had a link like this `<a [routerLink]="['/Application']">` it wouldn't work without `useAsDefault`, but my links are terminal: `<a [routerLink]="['/Application', 'Root']">`...

Comment: sorry i am unaware from these. thnx for comment. ill be thankful if your provide any link related to such things.

Comment: You can read through [Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), [Dev. Guides](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and [Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=router) on official site...

Answer (score 0):

I was working on angular 5 and got this error because I was passing parameter to click function like for iteration variable , which is wrong

```
 <td><a (click)="showReports({{row.site_id}})">{{row.site_name}}</a> </td>
```

so I solved this by using

```
 <td><a (click)="showReports(row.site_id)">{{row.site_name}}</a> </td>
```