# nested route does not load its component and does not route to main route

Tags: angular, parent-child, reload, router

When reloading the page with a routes child route `it does not load the component due to the nature of the component`, but it does not even route back to the main route. First, Is this supposed to be handled by me or is take care of by angular?

Update:
Hashstrategy did not work the way expected for second question.
In case of first I have route `/users/...` and a child `/users/vote` . When reloading `/users` it goes to `/login` but when reloading `/users/vote` it does not reload to that component (naturally) and does not go to /login as well

**Update**

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/vote', component: VoteComponent, name: 'VoteCmp',useAsDefault: true },
  {path: '/getapproval', component: GetapprovalComponent, name: 'GetapprovalCmp' },
  {path: '/userresults', component: ResultsComponent, name: 'UserresultsCmp' }
])
@Component({
  selector: 'users',
....
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]
})

export class UsersComponent{

    constructor(private _userdetails: Userdetails, private _router: Router){
      if (this._userdetails.usertypeDetails() === "" || this._userdetails.isLoggedin() === false){
          this._router.navigate( ['HomeCmp'] );
      }
      if(this._userdetails.usertypeDetails() === 'admin'){
          this._router.navigate( ['AdminCmp'] );
      }
  }
}
```

My vote component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'vote',
  template: `<div>Vote Component</div>`,
})
export class VoteComponent {

constructor(private _userdetails: Userdetails, private _router: Router){
      if (this._userdetails.usertypeDetails() === "" || this._userdetails.isLoggedin() === false){
          this._router.navigate( ['HomeCmp'] );
      }
      if(this._userdetails.usertypeDetails() === 'admin'){
          this._router.navigate( ['AdminCmp'] );
      }
}

}
```

My boot.ts has this

```
bootstrap(MainComponent,[Userdetails,ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Location, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, ROUTER_BINDINGS, bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue('/')]);
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser. If not please provide more information.

Comment: `HashLocationStrategy` is supposed to fix the first issue. It's not related to "otherwise". Actually I have no idea what this question is about. Please add some code that shows what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: What do you mean by *due to the nature of the component* and *it does not reload to that component (naturally)*?

Comment: I have created the component to redirect to login page in /users and /users/vote if username is set as blank (which it is when you reload the page). /users work fine but child of it /users/vote does not redirect.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't activate `/users/vote`... Try logging something in the constructors to see what component/route is activated when you reload.

Comment: tried location.path() in /users and pah loaded right -> This loads users and redirects correctly to /login. But the child route /users/vote gives error `Error: Unable to load script http://localhost:3000/users/client/boot.js(…)` The path is the same for /users as well which is bind(APP... ('/')) like above

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/">` to the html, there seams to be a bug with `APP_BASE_HREF`. I had [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35392186/1876949).

Comment: Thanks worked, it does seem to be a base path issue with child's child (nested route)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there's a bug with `APP_BASE_HREF` and nested routes (possibly [issue #5782](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5782)).

Solution (for now) is to add base tag to main html:

```
<base href="/">
```