# Bundling angular2 app with jspm

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification, jspm

I am new to jspm, and have worked with it for some months now, and really like it. I have developed a app in Angular2, and find jspm very smoothly to include other libraries. I use TypeScript.

Now I am trying to make a development build, where I would like to bundle my app, but I can't get it working properly. I don't get any issues before I bundle the app. I suspect it a problem in the way I configure system.js.

When I try to bundle with:

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/main public\app.js
```

And change my two script tags with a single one pointing to app.js, and copy the  bundle to my server, the app is not working due to these errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

And:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "head" ("


  [ERROR ->]</head>
<body>

"): AppComponent@21:2
Unexpected closing tag "html" ("
</body>

[ERROR ->]</html>
"): AppComponent@43:0
```

The last error seems to be a problem with the `<base href="/>` tag issue: [Template parse error: Unexpected closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392186/template-parse-error-unexpected-closing-tag), but I have the base tag just after the head. When I just change the scripts local I only get the first System import error?

My version of jspm:

```
0.16.32
Running against local jspm install.
```

My indes.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">

    <title>The Young Scholars Directory</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for YSI -->
    <link href="assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
<body>        

    <my-app>
      <div class="preloader">
        <img src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="preloader" />
      </div>
    </my-app>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        System.import("app/main");
    </script>

</body>    
</html>
```

config.js:

```
baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }, 

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "main",
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok the way you bundle it. I create my bundle like this:

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/main app-bundle.min.js --minify
```

And my html looks like this (bundle script tag after app selector):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
   <script src="app-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find a complete example here:

https://github.com/fintechneo/angular2-templates