# Angular2 routes: using HashLocationStrategy got a 404 not found error

Tags: routes, angular

Here is my project directory structure:

```
--root
   --app
      --app.ts
      --boot.ts
   --index.html 
   --node_modules
```

Here is my code:

boot.ts

```
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
    ]);
```

app.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'root', redirectTo: ['/pageA']},
    {path: '/page-a', name: 'pageA', component: PageA},
    {path: '/page-b', name: 'pageB', component: PageB}
])
```

html file:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

It works, but when I look at the console, it tell me `"http://localhost:63342/#/page-a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"`

In addition, when I refresh the page, it shows the "404 not found" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by using two ways, the first way is highly recommended.

1.see this post for details: [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set?lq=1)

```
<base href="/root/">
```

2.without setting `<base href...>`, I can't figure out the reason yet.

3.from documentation:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

Get hint from the official documentation and examples:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Notes from documentation:

```
Live example note

We have to be get tricky when we run the live example because the host service sets the application base address dynamically. That's why we replace the <base href...> with a script that writes a <base> tag on the fly to match.
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
We should only need this trick for the live example, not production code.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `useAsDefault` instead of `redirectTo`:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/page-a', name: 'pageA', component: PageA, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/page-b', name: 'pageB', component: PageB}
])
```

In the case of the HashLocationStrategy strategy, using  isn't necessary...

Comment: I actually tried both ways, but had the same error. BTW, why do you prefer useAsDefault? Is there any special reason that useAsDefault is better than redirectTo?

Comment: Which of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Did you try without the "<base href...>"?

Comment: I am using angular2 beta 0. Finally, I solve the problem by using <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>  instead of <base href="/">.

Comment: I think that you don't need <base href...>

Comment: In fact, using <base href...> will define à base path for all relative paths in the page... What is the value of document.location?

Comment: The value of document.location is: `http://localhost:63342/btnRoutes2/index.html`. Also, if I don't use <base href...>, it also works. I wonder why it also works?

Comment: Oh! It wasn't clear that you have a base path btnRoutes2. That's why <base href="/"> doesn't work... Using <base href="/btnRoutes2"> should work.