# Pass parameters in Angular2 @RouteConfig redirectTo

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Given a route config

```
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/app/index.html', name: 'default', redirectTo: ['/View1] }),
    new Route({ path: '/view1/:param1/:param2/', name: 'View1', component: View1Component })
])
```

and `param1`, `param2` being passed in as query parameters like so

```
http://legacy.com/app/index.html?param1=10&param2=15
```

how would I go about passing these parameters in the above `redirectTo` so that I'd end up with

```
http://legacy.com/app/#/view1/10/15
```

Is this possible to begin with?

Comment: I think angular should add this as a feature, all full redirects should automatically carry forward params and query params... it's how servers do it too

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/app', name: 'Default', redirectTo: ['/View1, {param1: 10, param2: 15}] }),
    new Route({ path: '/view1/:param1/:param2', name: 'View1', component: View1Component })
])
```

I modified the names an path a bit to make it compatible with the Angular2 style. If the `/app/` really comes before `index.html` then there is something wrong in your configuration. See also [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. However, `param1` and `param2` are not fixed, that's just the problem. If they're passed to a component I can grab them from `routeParams` but there's no way to get their runtime values inside the route config, is there?

Comment: No, what you can do is to redirect to a helper component and there redirect imperatively and passing runtime values. `constructor(router:Router) { router.navigateXxx(...);  }`. Actually you would change your `redirectTo:` to `component: SomeHelperComponent` and in this component you do the imperative redirection.