# Location and HashLocationStrategy stopped working in beta.16

Tags: angular

Error message

> VM556 angular2-polyfills.js:349Error: Token must be defined!(…)

or

> error TS2305: Module '"/node_modules/angular2/router"' has no exported member 'LocationStrategy'.
>   error TS2305: Module '"/node_modules/angular2/router"' has no exported member 'HashLocationStrategy'.
>   error TS2305: Module '"/node_modules/angular2/router"' has no exported member 'Location'.

How to fix

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**update >= rc.5**

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**update >= rc.0**

```ts
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF}  
from '@angular/common';  

import {BrowserPlatformLocation} from   '@angular/platform-browser';
```

**original**

Change

```ts
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
```

to

```ts
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/platform/common';
```

See also
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8229

Full list of moved exports:
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8230/files

```ts
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF}  
from 'angular2/platform/common';  

import {BrowserPlatformLocation} from   'angular2/src/platform/browser/location/browser_platform_location';
```

Another error that's commonly caused by this change is

> location.createComponent is not a function

Comment: basically `LocationStrategy` & `HashLocationStrategy` have been moved out to `angular2/platform/common` module, could you add this in your answer, so that would be more informative :)

Comment: as for people who are saying this is old please follow below link http://blog.ng-book.com/basic-routing-in-angular-2/