# Angular 2 get route no provider for Route

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 I want to be able to use `route.path` to.. get the path.

Inside a components constructor I have:

```
constructor(private route: Route) {}
```

So I would like to be able to call:

```
this.route.path
```

And for the app bootstrap I got:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,
[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]);
```

But I still get the *No Provider for Route!* error

Comment: If using outside the constructor just try once changing modifier in contructor to public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume what you to inject `Location` instead of `Route`. `Route` is for route configuration and there is no way for Angular to know which `Route` instance to inject.

`Location` provides the `path()` function to get the current URL.

Depending on the Angular2 version there are different paths where to import it from.

See also [Location and HashLocationStrategy stopped working in beta.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16)

**<= beta 15**

```ts
import {Location} from 'angular2/router';
```

**>= beta 16 < rc.0**

```ts
import {Location} from 'angular2/platform/common';
```

```ts
constructor(private location:Location) {
  console.log(location.path());
}
```

**>= rc.0**

```ts
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

Comment: You set me on the right track, it has to be `import { Location } from '@angular/common'; ` since 2.0.0-rc.0 If you add this, I'll accept :)

Comment: Right, forgot that it changed again

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` class can be injected. You can inject the `Router` one or `RouteParams`:

```
constructor(private router:Router,private params:RouteParams) {
  this.id = params.get('id');
}
```

If you need the path of the current route, inject rather the `Location` class and use its `path` method

```
constructor(private location:Location) {
  var path = location.path();
}
```

Comment: From where do you import RouteParams post beta (rc.1). It doesn't work to import it from @angular/router and I can't find where it says this anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ROUTER_BINDINGS instead.

Comment: ROUTER_BINDINGS has been deprecated (use ROUTER_PROVIDERS instead) since alpha41

Comment: too short for answer, you can use this as comment too.