# Running AngularDart on Apache

Tags: apache, dart, angular-dart

My Angular Dart site runs fine with pub serve. I would prefer to run it with Apache. When I enter the url jazzcat.loc/index.html I get the following browser errors:

```
GET http://jazzcat.loc/packages/browser/dart.js index.html:22 
GET http://jazzcat.loc/packages/polymer/polymer.dart package:polymer/polymer.dart:1 
An error occurred loading file: package:polymer/polymer.dart index.html:22 
GET http://jazzcat.loc/packages/angular2/platform/browser.dart package:angular2/platform/browser.dart:1 
An error occurred loading file: package:angular2/platform/browser.dart
index.html:22 GET http://jazzcat.loc/packages/jazzcat/app_component.dart package:jazzcat/app_component.dart:1 
An error occurred loading file: package:jazzcat/app_component.dart favicon.ico:1 
GET http://jazzcat.loc/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

The virtual host entry for the site is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName jazzcat.loc
  DocumentRoot /Volumes/Data/htdocs/jazzcat/web

  <directory /Volumes/Data/htdocs/jazzcat/web>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There is no .htaccess file

This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jazz Cat</title>
    <script>
      window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
      window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
    </script>

    <!-- For testing using pub serve directly use: -->
    <base href="/">
    <!-- For testing in WebStorm use: -->
    <!-- base href="/dart/web/" -->

    <link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
      <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</html>
```

I also tried using

```
<base href="/dart/web/">
```

It also errors out. I'm testing in the Chromium browser.

I've seen questions and answers here about routing. They seem to apply to routing beyond index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `pub serve` is meant to be used during development, if you want to use apache to serve your app, you might need to use `pub build` to transform (and optimize) your app to a *regular* html+javascript app, [here you might find more information](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html).

Comment: ... and either you switch to `HashLocationStrategy` or ensure the server supports HTML5 pushstate http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16

Comment: Now that I think about it, that makes sense.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, does HashLocationStrategy work with pub serve? I also can't reload pages and have read several questions and answers regarding the problem, but they don't mention under which environment they are implementing the fix. I don't want to waste time trying something that isn't meant to work with pub serve.

Comment: `pub serve` only supports `HashLocationStrategy`. AdaoJunior built a simple tool that allows to use `pub serve` to be used with `PathLocationStrategy` https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_serve_rewrites. Also for example when `nginx` is used as proxy that forwards to `pub serve` you can configure `nginx` to make `pub serve` make with `PathLocationStrategy` (I don't know nginx myself, it's just an example)