# What are Router Bindings actually used for

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

What are Router Bindings actually used for in Angular2 router. specially the Router 3.0 (newest Angular RC4 router)? Any working code or plunker?

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/ROUTER_BINDINGS-let.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name was just changed from `ROUTER_BINDINGS` to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` as were the `bindings` parameter of the `@Component()`, `@Directive()` or `@Pipe()` decorator was renamed to `providers` and they actually are the router implementation and services provided by the router implementation to be used injected in your code.

In the current version this feature is exported as function [`provideRouter()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/81d27daf0debcab528f60848b83b17c180315402/modules/%40angular/router/src/common_router_providers.ts#L92)

It looks like `ROUTER_PROVIERS` is going to be renamed again to `RouterModule` or similar with the introduction of modules in RC.5.

Comment: Then how do you bind( APP_BASE_HREF).toValue('/') in the new router

Comment: bootstrap(AppComponent, [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}])`. The imports have changed a bit as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16/36861629#36861629

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that the old "router bindings" are deprecated.  In new (Angular2/Router 3) code going forward, you should instead use "routing providers".

Here's a great article that describes the current routing model:

[Routing in Angular2 Revisited](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html)

You might also find this article helpful:

[Introduction to Angular 2 Routing](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-routing)

Finally, there's the Angular2 documentation itself:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Ok. so router bindings will no more be there. closing this.

Comment: It's just a rename and for backwards compatibility the old name is kept as well for some time.