# What are http bindings actually used for in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-http

What are  http bindings actually used for in Angular2? Any working codes or plunker? In the doc it is not documented and says use HTTP Providers.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/HTTP_BINDINGS-let.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html

Comment: Other than the bindings listed in the HTTP_Providers-let.html page?

Comment: [Check out the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/http/http.ts#L210). Doesn't look like it's good for anything, except leeching off providers :-). It looks like it's been this way since the first RC. Maybe it was used someway in the betas or even some time earlier (didn't check that far back). But it's deprecated now. I'm guessing part of that deprecation process was to just assign it to providers (where before deprecation, it probably has some other implementation)

Comment: @peeskillet Is it deprecated?

Comment: @Reza - any code implementations of where you might use http bindings?

Comment: That's what the docs you linked to says (Stability: Deprecated), and the ngdocs in the code I linked to

Comment: @peeskillet - ok yeah just saw.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `HTTP_BINDINGS` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is the same as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682856/217408

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` are a set of services that you can inject to your custom services and components or directives to make HTTP calls like

```
constructor(http:Http) {
  http.get(someUrl).subscribe(...)
}
```