# Angular2 routing in heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application in heroku, and I'm having trouble with the router. In localhost everything works like a charm, but when I deploy to heroku and try to access by any route that is not index i got 404 error, if I go index, then navigate trough page the routing occurs normally, unless I reload the page, then i get another 404, here's the piece of my package.json used by heroku
`"heroku-prebuild": "npm install http-server -g",
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --target=production --environment=prod && rsync -a dist/* .",
"start": "http-server dist/",`
Do I need to setup any express rewriting to be used in my Procfile?

Comment: Just a suggestion - search HTML5 routing in https://m.alphasights.com/using-nginx-on-heroku-to-serve-single-page-apps-and-avoid-cors-5d013b171a45#.1yk8sb720

Comment: You could also add `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}` to providers of your `AppModule`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Without `HashLocationStrategy` the only way to achieve that is using NGINX?

Comment: I just googled for Heroku and HTML5 routing. I don't know anything about Heroku.

Comment: Hello, have you found anything now? I have the same issue :)

Comment: @Adrien No. I had to change the history to use hash. It wasn't the best solution but it was the only that worked. I feel your pain :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem from the server , angular knows routing but your server doesnot know all these paths. The simple solution is to redirect all the paths to your main index.html . Like this,

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./dist/index.html'); // load our index.html file
});
```

This will not give any 404 error , all your paths will be redirected to main path i.e index.html and angular routing will run the same as it was in your local host .

Comment: I still got the issue . I applied this already . And it is only refresh page on a page not root  that is showing internal error