# how to make Angular2 router faster

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

in Angular 1 the application would take 1-3 seconds on initial load to get all resources and initialize. After that, navigating to different routes would just append #tab1 to the url and instantly switch to that route.

Is that still possible in Angular2?

Because following examples on angular.io each route re-loads entire app which takes 1-3 seconds while looking at a blank screen with a loader. It does not append a #path. Should I be using a different router to go back to that speed?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
```

here is my router config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'classes', component: ClassesComponent },
  { path: 'classes/:id', component: ClassDetailComponent },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'products', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'cache/clear', component: CacheComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: There is something substantially wrong with your setup if this is happening. Can you try to switch to `HashLocationStrategy`? Do you have a `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` element (or `APP_BASE_HREF` provided)?

Comment: Are you linking with `routerLink` ? Do you have `<base href="/">` in the head of the html ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer good to hear!   <base href="/">
 is located in head of index.html

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16

Comment: thanks it's definitely faster but all the routing is screwed up. as in, the path in address bar is one click behind and the tabs are not selecting correctly.

Comment: a lot of crazy things are happening. some paths still reload entire page and also other tabs in chrome!

Answer (score 0):

There is lazy-loading of routing . You can read about that here [lazy-loading-1](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) and [lazy-loading-2](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/Routing-and-Lazy-loading-@NgModules)