# External javascript library returns 404 on '{module}/dist/'

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, node-modules

Always having some trouble configuring an external project in Angular2.

I want to include [ng2-sharebuttons](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ng2-sharebuttons) in my project. (which does not seem to have a global `.d.ts` file?)

Although the `README.md` just says `npm install ng2-sharebuttons --save`, I know there are more things to this (`systemjs.config`& `typings`)

First I tried to configure `systemjs.config` having:

```
map{
     ......
     'ng2-sharebuttons' : 'node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons'
}
```

This at least fixed the `404` on `localhost/ng2-sharebuttons` but created a new `404` on `localhost/node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons`.

So, I added a main file, changing `systemjs.config` to

```
map{
     ......
     'ng2-sharebuttons' : 'node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons/dist/index.js'
}
```

But now this results in a `404` on every child of the `ng2-sharebuttons/dist`

I tried doing `typings install ng2-sharebuttons --save --global` and `typings install @types/ng2-sharebuttons --save --global` both with and without the `--global` flag.

So on my last hope I added a reference to see if that would work. Adding

`/// <reference path="../../node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons/dist/index.d.ts" />`

But this didn't change anything.

What did I forget? Why is this so hard? (Or am I just making it hard?)

Structure & files of `ng2-sharebuttons`:

[image]

And lastly, the error message currently being produced by Chrome:

[image]

Entire `systemjs.config.js`

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angularfire2' : 'npm:angularfire2/bundles/angularfire2.umd.js',
      'firebase' : 'npm:firebase',
      'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
      'ng2-sharebuttons' : 'npm:ng2-sharebuttons/dist/index.js',
      'ng2-social-share' : 'npm:ng2-social-share/bundles/ng2-social-share.js'
    },

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      firebase: {
        main: './firebase-browser.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

It throws an error `GET .... 404` but also a `XHR finished loading: GET ....` on the same component/service/file which seems quite weird.

Comment: Are you using the router? Have you tried with `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes I am using the router from `@angular/router` I've never heard about the `HashLocationStrategy` :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16 With the default `PathLocationStrategy` you need server support. Your problem could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Provided `PathLocationStrategy` with `HashLocationStrategy` but the error stays the same, It seems like I'm trying to 'import' from another project which is in my node_modules. (it seems to fire when a specific selector is placed)

Comment: I don't know about node modules. Just wanted to make sure it's not related to HTML5 pushState which often causes 404 when the server doesn't support it.

Comment: ah okay, well the application itself is working fine, router works like expected (hashed as well), just the `node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons/dist` returns some 404's

Comment: Can we see your full systemjs.config file?

Comment: @Gudin absolutely! edited the question

Comment: Can you try to add `defaultJSExtensions:true,` under your `System.config`? Like: `System.config({defaultJSExtensions:true,
    paths: {...`

Comment: is this by any chance related to your issue ?https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ng2-sharebuttons/issues/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this

```
map:{
   'ng2-sharebuttons' : 'npm:ng2-sharebuttons/dist'
},

packages: {
   app: {main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
   rxjs: {defaultExtension: 'js'},

   'ng2-sharebuttons': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
}
```

Comment: The quotes! Why didn't I think of that, thought you couldn't have a `-` in your package name. Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies but my corp proxy won't let me view the attached images...
But it looks as though you haven't statically exposed `node_modules` through your webserver.

You haven't specifically mentioned your server technology, but with node/express put this in app.js:

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './node_modules')));
```

Alternatively, use a build script to copy relevant js files to your express `scripts` (or similar) folder, and point your system.config mapping to the scripts folder instead.

Remember that the `/// <reference.../>` tag is only a hint to the Typescript transpiler and intellisense for type discovery. This is no longer necessary in Typescript 2, where @types/ are auto discovered.

Comment: I meant your server side technology rather than the front end. Can you confirm that you're serving the page through node/express or similar?

Comment: This is the result of an `npm start` running `lite-server` command

Comment: Because other node_module references work fine, i suspect that systemjs is struggling to interpret the module format of the js file. First confirm in chrome dev tools that the js file is indeed downloaded to your browser. Secondly add `meta: {
            "node_modules/ng2-sharebuttons/dist/index.js": { format: "global" }` to your system.config.

Comment: Again... apologies that i can't even see your "message produced by Chrome" error image.... Its laughable but i'm still the only one helping you. Albeit blind.

Comment: doing so results in a `404` on `localhost/app`, doesn't seem to be the solution for angular 2 :/