# Angular2: Error: Cannot match any routes, when typing url in the browser address bar

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router

I'm trying to implement routing in my Angular 2 application. My objective is to be able to use the browser address bar to display a specific object by the id.

Here are my routes:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'intervention/:id',
        component: InterventionMainDisplay
    },
    {
        path: 'intervention',
        component: InterventionMainDisplay
    }
];
```

I don't understand why when i enter in the browser address bar:
http://localhost:3000/intervention
or
http://localhost:3000/intervention/15893
.. none of my routes are matched.

In the index.html I have `<head><base href="/" />`

I checked the router module configuration is loaded:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        RouterModule.forRoot (appRoutes) ], ...
```

Here is the full error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''
    at new Error (native)
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
```

Comment: Try enabling `HashLocationStrategy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16/36861629#36861629

Comment: Yes it does work when enabling HashLocationStrategy !! Now the url to type is http://localhost:3000/#/intervention/1239817  ( the # is added in the url).  So now I ask: why it does'n work with the PathLocationStrategy, the default strategy ?

Comment: The server needs to support HTML5 pushState for `PathLocationStrategy` to work (some simple rewrites)

Comment: ok, and I'm using nom liteserver that does not support html5 pushState. The application is aimed to work on IIS 8.5.

Comment: I don't use these servers. There are lot of such questions here on SO with answers with HTML5 pushState configurations for all kinds of servers.