# angular2 <base href="/"> confusing browser

Tags: angular

if I build an angular2 app, I can easily go into my dev folder, double-click on my index.html and the browser will open the page and get all resources displaying the app right - without any local dev-server.

But when I add the `<base href="/">` tag in index.html that I NEED for angular's router to work, the browser can't load the page anymore.

Using a dev-server this works fine.

Can someone explain me what's the reason for that ??

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Comment: I added it directly after the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Why does angular need that tag to be present for router to work ?

Comment: To know what is the static part of the URL and what part it has to change on route changes (dynamic part). This is relevant when the root directory is not `/` like `/somefolder/myapp/index.html`

Answer (score 17):

When you use `<base href="/">` and open the index.html directly base is considered to be a file `file:///C:/`, or similar, depending on where your file is.

One solution is to use relative path: with `<base href="./">` base will be current folder where your file is. You can use this if you have to run app from USB stick, for example

Comment: When I had `<base href="/">` my angular 2 solution was working locally with nodejs but when I copied the files over the IIS on our server I got 404's for all the scripts and css files in index. Adding the `.` before the `/` make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a virtual directory in IIS 7.5 named /ang2 that points to C:\Apps\hello-world\dist.  I am building the project with angular-cli (ie: "ng build --target=production" or "ng build target=development").
If I change base href to ./ it works.  I also got it working with ./ang2.
I have not tested any routing yet as this is a just a project created with the command "ng new hello-world".