# @angular/core/testing has no exported member 'MockApplicationRef'

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I want to run my old angular2 unit-test with new RC4 version, but
I have a problem.

What happened to MockApplicationRef ?

What I should use here instead ?

```
provide(ApplicationRef, { useClass: MockApplicationRef})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure this is a delayed answer for this ticket, but if you arrived here from Google like me, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set)

Basically MockApplicationRef is replaced by TestBed and importing a new provider should do the trick:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {APP_BASE_HREF}    from '@angular/common';
...
...
beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
  ]
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also base-href implementation added, just in case

Answer (score 1):

For future onlookers. I renamed one of my classes, and it was not updated. So make sure that your Component/class is named correctly, and also check the correct import path.