# angular 2 routing / EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Update: I fixed this original issue by adding

```
<base href=".">
```

in the head of the _layout.

But now I get this below. Can anyone see why from looking at the [project files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kanvjk4boofs1wr/AngularJS2Setup_error.zip?dl=0)?

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any
>   routes: 'Welcome'
>    /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser//bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:937

---

I was trying to get my routing working on this tutorial I was going through and ran into this error. I can't explain why it's happening so I'm [uploaded the project so anyone can see it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kanvjk4boofs1wr/AngularJS2Setup_error.zip?dl=0).

I get the error in the image. I don't see what's wrong w/ my app component & thinking it's something else. Can anyone look at the code & tell me how to resolve this, please? Been on this 2 days. Using VS 2015 Community.

[image]

Comment: In your index.html or _Layout.cshtml (whichever you are using), add `<base href="/">` inside head tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 router no base href set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set)