# path: "**" for not found page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I`am use routing in angular 2 with typescript.

In main `index.html` i add `<base href="">`, not `<base href="/">`, because i need special route for my project, and everything is working, but i have some problem with not found page. Here is a part of my `app.route.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { component: LaskComponent, path: "table_per" },
    { component: LaskComponent, path: "table_per/:id" },
    { component: DashboardComponent, path: "dashboard" },
    { component: LoginComponent, path: "login" },
    { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "login" },
    { component: HomeComponent, path: "home" },
    { component: NotFoundComponent, path: "not_found" },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "not_found" },
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

And this is `NotFoundComponent`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    template: ' 
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Not found page</h1>
        </div>',
})
export class NotFoundComponent {};
```

When i start a project in chrome on `localhost`, i redirect to `localhost/login`, and everything is OK, but when i check a not found page like this `localhost/sxvknb`, i get this page `localhost/sxvknb/login` and redirect in login form again. What is the problem? Maybe with

```
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "not_found" }
```

Launch my project i can start with 3 deploys:

[image]

Comment: You can provide `APP_BASE_HREF` instead of `<base href="/">` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might fix your issue:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, routing /* or RouterModule */], 
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
]);
```

See also [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256)

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me, when i laucnh my app in `localhost` its work great, but when i start my app from server: `10.10.0.1/object/go` i take a not found page from my component, whats the problem?

Comment: Either your server doesn't support pushState, or you need a different path for `<base href="/object/go">` (or similar with `APP_BASE_HREF`).

Comment: before a launch, i can choose to start 

- /go
or
- /python

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that "I can choose ..."