# Moving angular 2 application to apache server environtment make error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have create an angular 2 application using the angular-cli like as follow

```
ng new my-angualr-app
```

after thay I have build this application on the production mode

```
ng build --prod
```

the I got the `dist` folder.

Finally I move the folder to my apache servers `var/www/html` directory but the angular 2 application is not working fine.

I could not figureout the issue. Why this is not working. The application working fine on the production mode in local environment, while running the command `ng serve --prod`

## The console error output is here

[image]

## The Network tab shows 404 status. But the files are resides in the same directory

[image]

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: You might need something like http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Sorry, the link on the solution is not working

Comment: Try enabling `HashLocationStrategy` like explained in the link "Dup of ..." (` providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy]` and tell us if you still get the error.

Comment: Still I got the same 404 the files css and js not found error

Comment: I have update the network status on the question too

Comment: It works when I put all files into my Apache server /www/html directory directly but it fails when i keep all files on /www/html/dist folder. Why it is happen

Comment: Then you need to set the `<base href="/dist">` in the `<head>` element or provide `APP_BASE_HREF` like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256 (and like mentioned in the answer below)

Comment: I put <base href="/dist"> but it again show the error

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the dist folder, copy the contents of the dist folder, and make sure the base href is correct

Comment: The problem I found on the network tab is all the file below are hashed and the status of the files are 404

styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.bundle.css
inline.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.js
styles.b2328beb0372c051d06d.bundle.js
main.6cc85e1296261ab75a89.bundle.js
favicon.ico

Comment: The solution is work for me copy the content instead of copy the /dist forlder. why it happens?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your setup. Is your angular app being deployed to the root path? (ie. www.place.com, instead of www.place.com/virtualdir) Is your server doing routing rewrites to root for non-directories?

Answer (score 0):

I Think You are doing it in wrong way, I am sharing my way of doing-

First of all I use git for repository. So I push my angular2 code which was created by `angular-cli`. By default, The `dist` folder is not added in the repository. So I let it as it is.

After that, I clone my angular2 code in the production server in `var/www/html` and run the `ng build --prod` there. So, It creates the `dist` folder for the production server.

I think you can try in this way. It really works for me(in my several projects)