# Angular 2 defining base url

Tags: angular

On my server I can´t put the Angular 2 files into the root folder. So my path is /another-folder. I put that into my index.html like this:

```
<base href="/another-folder">
```

When I open up the URL http://servername/another-folder the app does not load as the files can´t be found. The app searches for the files in the root. E.G. http://servername/main.bundle.js

Is there any other place where I have to define the base URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [routing /* or RouterModule */], 
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
]);
```

See also [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256)

Comment: Ok. In my local environment it uses the new path. But on my server it still doesn´t find the resources.

Comment: Sounds like your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/36310728#36310728. You need to configure your server for HTML5 pushState.

Comment: So i am doing a ng serve as I use Angular 2 CLI. And I have to configure pushState there somewhere?

Comment: I assume "my server" is a different server than `ng serve`, and this server needs to be configured to support HTML5 pushState. Altenatively you can switch the Angular router to use `HashLocationStrategy`, then the server doesn't need to support pushState.

Comment: In what file is that?

Comment: app.module . . .

Answer (score 4):

I think the trailing slash is missing

```
<base href="/another-folder/">
```

At least for me this is working without reverting to TypeScript