# URL grows in Angular2 when routing to app in a sub-directory

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404

My Angular2 app is deployed in a sub-directory of a website on IIS. I use the following command to build it. (--bh sets the sub-directory as the root for the app):

```
ng build --bh testdna --no-aot --dev
```

I then use routing with in the app as follows

app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DnaPlotComponent } from './dna-plot/dna-plot.component';

export const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: DnaPlotComponent }];
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
...
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

**Every time** the page is refreshed the URL has the sub-directory appended to it. This means the URL grows infinitely and fails to refresh, resulting in a 404. Here is an example of what I am seeing.

```
https://develop.domain.com/dnaplot/dnaplot#/dnaplot/
```

The original URL called is:

```
https://develop.domain.com/dnaplot
```

Any ideas to stop this happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `<base href="...">` or provide `APP_BASE_HREF` that points to the deployed path.

For more details see [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256)

Providing `APP_BASE_HREF` is usually the better approach, because it only influences the router, while `<base href="...">` influences other stuff like SVG references.

A route with an empty path `''` and no child routes should have `pathMatch: 'full'`

```ts
export const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: DnaPlotComponent , pathMatch: 'full'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was simply to set base href to an empty string, ie. `<base href="">`.

The router seems to be 'aware' of the `--bh testdna`  in the original build command and therefore there is no need to re-state the sub-dir in the href tag.