# Cannot match any routes: base href suffix

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular application I've deployed to an IIS web application at `my-machine:8111/my-app`. I've set both the base tag and the APP_BASE_HREF value mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34535256/1680677) to the absolute URL for the app: `https://my-machine:8111/my-app/`.

For some reason, when I initially load the application—when I hit that absolute URL—I get an error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-app'

I don't know why the web application name is being read as part of the Angular route. I'm sure the base URL is correct: If I take of the last slash or try a relative path I can't even load the application.

Why isn't it routing to `/`? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`APP_BASE_HREF` is used in the following manner: `{{host}}:{{port}}{{APP_BASE_HREF}}`, and with your `APP_BASE_HREF` set to the full string `"https://my-machine:8111/my-app/"` it's expecting that to be appended into the {{APP...}} section. It only wants the part after `{{host}}:{{port}}` since those two items are handled by your server already.

Setting `APP_BASE_HREF` to `"/my-app"` will solve the current problem, but your IIS server may require addition tuning such as route-parameter forwarding before your app is 100% functional.

Comment: You were right. I took a closer look at what was happening, and `/my-app/` was getting expanded like a path. The final solution was to do `//my-app\\', and then it would convert to `/my-app/`.