# "Error: No base href set." after upgrade to Angular 8

Tags: angular

After completing an update from Angular 5.x to 8.0.1, my application compiles but I get the following error at runtime (using `ng serve`):

> Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

I've looked at other posts such as: [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set), however, my app already has the HTML base element in it.  My `index.html` is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<app-root></app-root>
</html>
```

I can solve the problem by adding:

```
{
  provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
  useValue: '/'
}
```

to my `app.modules.ts`, but I'm more interested in understanding why this is now needed, when a bare bones app created with `ng new` works without this provider.

Comment: It may not have any effect on the error message, but you should add a `body` to the HTML file, and put the `app-root` component in it.

Comment: try setting base href for once in `ng serve --baseHref= /`

Comment: @ConnorsFan That _was_ actually the problem, that file was generated (as far as I know) by the Angular 4 CLI and has never been touched since, so I totally overlooked that.  If you want to put that in as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that `index.html` is a valid HTML file by adding the `body` element, in which you can insert the Angular root component:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```