# Angular Nested Routing Issue: 404 Error on Page Reload

Tags: angular

I'm using nested routing in my Angular app, which works fine with routerLink. However, when I reload the page or type the URL manually, I get a 404 error.

I'm importing some dependencies in the index.html. Is it possible they are causing the problem?, and how can I fix it?

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: How are you running the server? Local or deployed somewhere?

Comment: I run it locally

Comment: With the angular cli or something else? Usually this means that the server isn't configured correctly, but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: The problem is solved when I added
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy ,useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],

to my app.module file, but it keeps adding # in the URL and I don't think it's a good solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by using this code inside the main HTML file

```html
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

For more information: [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set?lq=1)

I hope my post helps